# Why is CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE pre-set with single-config generators on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmake, ninja

I was trying to set the default build type to `Release` with CMake, using the method described [here](https://blog.kitware.com/cmake-and-the-default-build-type/) (straight from the horse's mouth). This method checks if `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is already set, and sets it to `Release` only if its value was empty. This works fine on macOS and Linux. However, on Windows, `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is already set to `Debug` from the default. Why does this happen and how can I work around it, so that I can reliably set the default build type to `Release`?

---

To try this out yourself, create a trivial CMake file:

```
# CMakeLists.txt

project(Foo)
message(STATUS "Build type is '${CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE}'")
```

Then use with with a single-configuration generator, such as `cmake . -G"NMake Makefiles"` or `cmake . -GNinja`. In both cases, on Windows I see: `Build type is 'Debug'`. On other platforms I see `Build type is ''`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is getting set on the `project` line. Before that it is empty. Thus, checking whether `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is empty and setting a default value can be done *before* this line.

Here is a discussion about this: https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/19401